# HLS continuously generated segments

Tags: ffmpeg, hls

I wanted to know how can I stream through HLS continuously created segments. I basically have a server that gives me 2 images every second and I want them to be streamed asap to an user via HLS until server finishes generating them. With ffmpeg I can create segments and playlist but I think the command is related to a single input and not to a growing input right? Anyone can explain me how should it be?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294919/can-you-stream-images-to-ffmpeg-to-construct-a-video-instead-of-saving-them-t — are you intending to do this from a program? The HLS muxer should be able to refresh the segment index and delete old segments, so you can use it for live streaming.

Comment: so regarding the link you published.. the situation is the same but I can't define when images will stop generating. Basically I have to stream a VOD after images start generating and while they are still generating. I intend to use ffmpeg for the encoding from images to hls and send it to apache webserver. Problem is I need to do it on-the-fly.